# Inference of Beta-Bernoulli Distribution

Tags: computational-statistics, hierarchical-bayesian, variational-bayes, beta-binomial-distribution, variational-inference

Assume $x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n$ follows a $Bern(\pi_0)$, Let $y_{ik}$ follows $Beta(\alpha,\beta)$, $i\in \{1,\cdots, n\}$, and $k\in \{1,\cdots, K\}$. Let $z_k$ follows a Bernoulli Distribution with a probability of $Bern(\mathbf{x'y_k})$, where ${\mathbf{x'y_k}}$ is constrained to be $[0,1]$. If I have the data of $z_{1:K}$ and $y_{1:n,1:K}$, then how to estimate latent variables $x_{1:n}$.

I have tried CAVI or SVI to estimate $x$. In CAVI, the expectation part is impossible to calculate. $$ E_{q_{y_k}}(z_k\log(\sum x_iy_{ik}+(1-z_k)\log(1-\sum x_i y_{ik}))) =z_kE_q(\log\cfrac{x'y_k}{1-x'y_k})+E_q(\log(1-x'y_k))  $$
In SVI, the distribution of $y_k, z_k|x$ does not belong to an exponential family. I wonder are there any methods to solve this estimation.

Comment: 1. What is CAVI?  What is SVI?  2. With reference to your last line, it doesn't matter what distribution the $y$ follow, as they are known and you aren't trying to estimate the parameters of that distribution (which wouldn't require any knowledge of $x$ or $z$ were you to do so.)

Comment: It also matters how you enforce the constraint on $x'y_k$; if you simply use $\min (1,x'y_k)$ as the probability or if you impose a constraint on the $x$ such that for all $k$, $x'y_k < 1$.

Comment: CAVI shorts for Coordinate Ascent Variational Inference and SVI for Stochastic Variational Inference. Yes, to make it easier, I assume the $y$s are known. And for the second comment, I simply use min(1, x'y_k) as the probability.

Comment: What do you do when you end up with $x'y_k \geq 1$ or $=0$?  Your logit function won't do you any favors in those situations.

Comment: If x'y_k \ge 1, I set it to be 1-1e-5 and if x'y_k == 0, i set it to be 1e-5.